# Search for questions that I asked but have not accepted answers to

Tags: support, search, accepted-answer

Is there any way to search a site for all questions that I asked, that have answers and that I have not accepted an answer to? I often forget to check off accepted answers because I don't know of a quick way to filter for these.

Comment: Related: [How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/how-can-i-view) and [Find all of my unaccepted questions across all stackexchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139429/find-all-of-my-unaccepted-questions-across-all-stackexchange-sites), which is closed as a dupe of that first one but is arguably slightly better. Rather than vote to close this post, I'm going to edit it to focus on the single-site case, since that's what the answer assumes (reasonably so, since this was asked in mid-2009).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using the search feature

> ```
> user:me hasaccepted:0
> ```

To ensure it also has an answer

> user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1

After looking at your username, I'd like to clarify that it is `user:me` for everyone. The fact that your display name is also "me" is just a coincidence. Alternatively, you can replace `user:me` with `user:###`, with a userid replacing the pound signs.

Comment: +1 for confusing me with me

Comment: How can I search for all questions of this type across the entire stackexchange network? There are unresolved questions on multiple sites that I'd like to add accepted answers to.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the following link:

[Questions, where you didn't accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20hasaccepted:0)

See [search ninja](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) for more hints to search on StackExchange sites.