# How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?

Tags: support, search, accepted-answer, global-search

I mean to get back them, really I do. So, how can I view all my unaccepted questions across the Stack Exchange network?

[Searching for `user:me hasaccepted:0` works for a single site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers), but the stackexchange.com search doesn't work the same way (it searches for the text). Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to achieve what you want by leveraging a cross-database query script. The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/330763/find-all-my-unaccepted-question-network-wide?accountid=1971679) does that for user [Nate Kerkhofs](https://stackexchange.com/users/1971679/nate-kerkhofs).

The query requires an accountid and that one can be found by visiting your network account on StackExchange.com and then take the id from the url. Yours is [439169](https://stackexchange.com/users/84450/d3vid), mine is [281857](https://stackexchange.com/users/281857/rene) and that of user [void.pointer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/178299/void-pointer) is [52844](https://stackexchange.com/users/52844/void-pointer)

```sql
---- accountid: Account on stackexchange.com ! "In the url on stackexchange.com"

-- create url from dbname
IF OBJECT_ID ( '#siteurl', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL 
    DROP PROCEDURE #siteurl;
GO

-- create url based on dbname
create procedure #siteurl
   @dbname nvarchar(250),
   @res nvarchar(250) OUT
   as
   begin
      declare @pos integer
      declare @rec nvarchar(250)
      set @res = @dbname
      set @pos = CHARINDEX('.', @dbname)
      if (@pos > 0 ) 
      begin
         set @rec = substring(@dbname, @pos+1, len(@dbname))
         exec #siteurl @rec,  @rec output
         set @res = @rec 
                  + '.' 
                  + substring(@dbname, 0, @pos) 
      end
   end;
go

declare @accountid int = ##accountid:int##  -- 93484

-- all databases
declare  db_c cursor for select [name] 
                         from sys.databases 
                         where database_id > 5 -- skip master, temp, model, msdb, Data.SE
                     
declare @db_c_name sysname   -- holds name of db after fetch
declare @sql nvarchar(max) -- holds build up sql string

-- result table
create table #all_questions ( site nvarchar(250)
                            , title nvarchar(250)
                            , qid int);
                            
open db_c
fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
while(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
begin
    set @sql = N'use '+ QUOTENAME(@db_c_name) +';
declare @url nvarchar(250)
exec #siteurl ''' + @db_c_name  + ''', @url output
declare @userid int = null
select @userid = id 
from users where accountid =  '+ cast(@accountid as nvarchar) + '
if @userid is not null 
begin
  insert into #all_questions
  select @url
       , title
       , id
  from posts p
  where owneruserid = @userid
  and p.posttypeid = 1 --Q
  and answercount>0
  and acceptedAnswerid is null
end;'
               
    exec (@sql)
   fetch next from db_c into @db_c_name
end;
close db_c;
deallocate db_c;

select replace(site,'.StackExchange','') as [site]
     , 'http://' 
     + site 
     + '.com/'
     + 'q'
     + '/'
     + cast(qid as nvarchar)
     + '|'
     + title
from #all_questions
order by 1 asc

drop table #all_questions
```

The outcome of the query loos like this:

[image: nate kerkhofs unaccepted questions]

Keep in mind that SEDE is only refreshed once a week, on sunday.

Comment: Using this method, can I sort oldest (on top) to newest (on bottom)?

Comment: Only if you bring in creationdate  from the per site query to the #results table @void.pointer

Comment: I put in my user ID and I don't get posts that I own in the results. I'm grabbing the number in the URI seen on the profile page. Is this correct?

Comment: @void.pointer the id found [here](http://stackexchange.com/users/52844/void-pointer)? You need your networkprofile id

Comment: Is it possible to make a version that automatically uses the user ID for whatever user is currently running the search? [Similar to how you can include `user:me` in a search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16873/351462).

Comment: @StevenVascellaro that used to work with `##UserID:int##` but a change in the emailhash rendered that  functionality useless for most if not all users: see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209605/why-is-the-userid-parameter-not-populated-in-data-explorer-anymore so I never tried it since.

Comment: The first line of your script has a typo. `---- accountid: Account on stackexchnage.com`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro all my scripts have that typo so I can easily find plagiarism ... or maybe I find that a plausible explanation for my screw up. Anyhow, now fixed.

Comment: The query returns an incorrect domain for questions on sites that have a unique URL name. (i.e. script returns `http://stackoverflow.meta.com/` instead of `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/`)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some Python code that will run the query on each Stack Exchange site on which you have an account. For me it opens the search on each site in a separate tab (not a separate window), though that may depend on your browser's configuration. You'll need to plug your own username and id into `http://stackexchange.com/users/3370439/kuzzooroo?tab=accounts`. You can change the `days=60` code if you want to change how far back in time this looks. Hat tip to @psubsee2003's answer on [my near-duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221544/getting-a-list-of-questions-ive-asked-for-which-i-should-accept-an-answer) for constructing a good model query string.

```
# This code requires the Beautiful Soup library, which doesn't come with Python.
# Depending on your setup you'll need to run something like `pip install beautifulsoup4`
# to get the library.
import datetime
import re
import webbrowser
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urlparse import urlparse

today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
old_day = today - datetime.timedelta(days=60)
date_str = "{}..{}".format(old_day, today)

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen("http://stackexchange.com/users/3370439/kuzzooroo?tab=accounts"))
sites = set()
for tag_a in soup("a"):
    pr = urlparse(tag_a["href"])
    if re.match("/users/[0-9]", pr.path) and '' != pr.netloc:
        sites.add(pr.netloc)
for site in sites:
    url = "http://{}/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1+lastactive%3A{}+".format(site, date_str)
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Comment: failing a site-side feature this is great. accepting untested. does this include meta sites?

Comment: Yes, it does get meta sites.

Comment: BTW, this code requires the Beautiful Soup library, which doesn't come with Python. Depending on your setup you'll need to run something like `pip install beautifulsoup4` to get the library.

Comment: @kuzzooroo You should add that last comment to the answer.

Comment: @gerrit, I added a comment at the top of the code. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: @kuzzooroo Good.

Comment: I would not expect the average user on every site to have the technical skill to implement this answer. (Consider cooking.SE).  May I ask that people throw their support behind this feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139429/find-all-of-my-unaccepted-questions-across-all-stack-exchange-sites)?

Comment: I agree with @TravisBemrose in that a python snippet is not really easy to implement. I have worked with Python before, and even then, getting it to work is not simple: installing Python, changing your path, turning this into a snippet, finding and inserting your user ID... It's better than nothing, but it's far from usable.