# Why is the ##UserID## parameter not populated in Data Explorer anymore?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

### Environment

I'm logging in using the OpenID from http://openid.stackexchange.com and using Chrome 31.0.1650.57 m if that matters.

### Steps to reproduce:

Log in to [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and [compose a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new), for example, like:

```sql
DECLARE @MyUserID INT = ##UserID:int##

SELECT TOP 1
    Id AS [Post Link],
    Score AS [Score],
    CreationDate AS [Creation Date]
FROM
    Posts
WHERE
    OwnerUserId = @MyUserID AND
    PostTypeId IN (2, 3)
ORDER BY
    CreationDate
DESC
```

Then press the Run Query button and see if the UserID field is filled with your own user ID like shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

### Question:

Did something changed on the `##UserID##` parameter (for example, that it's not supported anymore)?

- If so, then there is an outdated [help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) paragraph about it (*What's the point of logging in*).
- If not, it is a bug which is there about three days (I've been waiting since I noticed that you were going to do some changes to Data Explorer, but it remains there, hence my question).

Comment: works for me in IE11

Comment: works for me in Chrome as well... sorry...

Comment: Are you sure you are logged in? ie, your name is in the right top of your screen, not an login link?

Comment: @rene, I'm logged in for sure. Now I've cleared also the whole history data (all of the types). No change... I'm using Data Explorer quite frequently and I noticed this about 3 days ago on 2 computers...

Comment: I think it's related to OpenID provider. With this account I'm using Google as my provider and it's indeed not working, field not populated. [My loyal sock](http://data.stackexchange.com/users/12447/shadow-of-the-shadow) is using Stack Exchange OpenID and it's working. @rene can you confirm too? (i.e. what is your OpenID provider)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm using Google as OpenId provider and it is working @ShaWizDowArd

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, if we are talking about OpenID, then I'm using [this one](http://i.imgur.com/LqyKqnR.png) (I hope I got the point where to find this information).

Comment: @rene and TLama yeah, this pretty much nullifies my assumption. Oh well, hope a dev or Tim Stone will come for the rescue.

Comment: Can we blame this on caching? Maybe it depends on which side of the ocean you are? I'm on the good side...

Comment: @rene nope, it's one of the rare occasions when cache is not to blame... ;)

Comment: It is, @TLama - neither login credentials nor account information are shared between data.SE and the rest of the network, so this was implemented by assuming that email hashes would be identical between them... However, as ShaWizDowArd's answer attests, this is becoming less and less of a valid assumption due to privacy concerns surrounding the use of Gravatar. It might be possible to reimplement this using the API to authenticate, but... That's *probably* overkill.

Comment: @Shog9, ok, but isn't there any way to reset those `EmailHash` values to force them to refresh ?

Comment: Yes, @TLama - as Sha describes in his answer, if you manually set your avatar to Gravatar it should work. However, this should still be considered an implementation detail at this point and likely to break without notice. (I've updated Sha's answer to clarify all of this)

Comment: @Shog9 API integration *is* actually on my todo list as a nice optional feature, especially if I can convince Nick to put network account IDs in the Users table too.

Comment: Oh, hey, @Tim - AccountId has been available for a little bit now; get fancy...

Comment: @Shog9 Yep, been trying to find the time to get started, should have something soonish.

Comment: @Shog9: I just hit this issue and none of the listed workarounds have fixed the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: Gotta wait for a SEDE patch at this point, @mrhen

Comment: @Shog9: Waa, all of these free services aren't happening quickly enough! I demand a refund! (But seriously, thanks for the update. ;)

Comment: @Shog9 Why was this changed to status-bydesign?  I can't imagine the developers *intended* for the ##UserId## parameter to not work for a subset of users.  Have they been notified of this issue *(which still exists, months later)*?

Comment: Yes, @Blue. And yes, it's very much by-design (and at this point, shouldn't work for anyone) - sadly, a few unscrupulous companies were using the same information to spam users on these sites.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't understand, Gravatar has nothing to do with this; that was just poor design choice, it's completely unnecessary for this function.  You have my openId identity, which you have mapped to my userId in the database.  It should be a simple matter to make a single call to retrieve that value and fill that in.  There would be no way to use this to "spam users".

Comment: Actually, no @Blue: SEDE is completely separate from SE's account database. You can even download it and use it for your own data if you want. It would be possible to authenticate with SE's API and obtain your account ID that way, which could then be mapped to your user ID for a specific query... But this will take some doing. More to the point: that's *not* how it was being done before, which is why this stopped working when we started stripping email hashes.

Comment: I have created help documentation update post https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328279/282428
Hopefully it will be updated soon.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

OK, I cracked it.

The bottom line is it's because Stack Exchange changed the Gravatar hashing algorithm recently, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11037):

> A fairly recent article on ArsTachnica, regarding how using [Gravatars
>    can leak an email address](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/07/got-an-account-on-a-site-like-github-hackers-may-know-your-e-mail-address/) has prompted us to make some changes to how
>    we produce the gravatar hash (under certain circumstances).

And the code to find the UserID per site is: ([source](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Models/Site.cs))

```cs
string hash = Util.GravatarHash(user.Email);
try
{
    return cnn.Query<int?>("select top 1 Id from Users where EmailHash = @hash order by Reputation desc", new {hash}).FirstOrDefault();
}
catch
{
    // Allow this to fail, its not critical
}
```

Which means Data Explorer is looking for hash that was changed. It didn't affect all users (see "under certain circumstances" in Oded's reply).

**Note**: at some point after writing this answer, SE removed the hash from the database and blanked out all existing Gravatar hashes, i.e. the value of EmailHash in Users table is always null now. This means there's no way to get the user id parameter auto populated any longer.

Comment: WIZARDRY!​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Shog thanks for editing! Any alternative to find UserID then, so that Data Explorer won't stay in the dark?

Comment: I'm affected and I've had a gravatar profile picture for years (so I can't change to using gravatar). Is there another workaround?

Comment: @Bohemian try changing to something else then back to Gravatar, hopefully it will "reset" the hash and next Monday (today if you're quick enough) it will be fine.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I just hit this issue and none of the listed workarounds have fixed the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: @MrHen sorry, not really.

Comment: For me it stopped to work as well. I'll resolve this by modifying all the queries only for my private use by hardcocing my user ID. Not so cool, but I'm using that tool pretty frequently. You can do it too, @MrHen.

Comment: Maybe they changed the hash again... or ditched it as Shog warned.

Comment: That's why there are tons of duplicate queries with different user ids on data.SE

Comment: @Lankymart yep, good point! :/

Comment: I am already using gravatar as my profile image but user id autofilling feature is still not working

Comment: @AbdulRauf what I wrote in the last paragraph (before editing now) came true, they removed it. Edited the answer to be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small userscript, [SEDE User ID Autofiller](https://stackapps.com/q/8136/34061), to restore this functionality for users (like me) where the standard functionality doesn't work. As a bonus, it will autofill `##AccountId##` parameters with your network account ID for cross-site queries.