# Help section update related to ##UserID## in data.stackexchange

Tags: discussion, status-completed, data-explorer

On [help page of data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), It is stated that:

> The ##UserId## parameter is treated specially for users who are logged
>   in. If they have an account on the target site that shares the email
>   used in their Data Explorer account, their user ID on that site will
>   be automatically populated.

and

> Automatic population of ##UserId## fields when possible (if you have a
>   matching email)

This is no longer true. As per [Why is the ##UserID## parameter not populated in Data Explorer anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209605/282428) this bug is **by design** as a result of the removal of Gravatar hashes for user privacy. So I think help section should be updated.

PS: I know that [SEDE User ID Autofiller](https://stackapps.com/questions/8136/sede-user-id-autofiller) can be used to resolve this issue. I am wondering why this feature hasn't been natively implemented as stated in the help section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made those changes and submitted a [Pull Request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/91) to have those changes merged to master.

Do know there are still older pending pull requests for Nick to handle. Allow for more then 6 to 8 weeks to get this into production.

I didn't check if the Active Directory login actually does lead to a working autocomplete `##userid##` on queries on the internal SEDE instance. That might be a reason the PR gets rejected.