# When running a query in SEDE that needs UserId as input parameter, add an option to indicate the ID of the logged-in user, based on the selected site

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

Feature request: When running a query in SEDE that needs the UserId as input parameter, add an option to indicate the ID of the logged in user, based on the SE website they selected to run the query on.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I missed that feature too (it [used to work like that in the beginning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209605/295232), and the documentation mentioned it too), so I decided a while ago to [write a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8136/34061) to enable this. It also works for parameters named `AccountId` which are automatically filled with your network profile ID.