# How can I find all my questions (all stackexchange sites)?

Tags: support, questions, search

I'm active on many stackexchange sites, and I've asked a question recently. I know the topic of the question, but not the exact tile, and more specifically, I forgot on which site I had been asking (it's not always clear which is the correct site to ask).

So is there a way to list all my questions on *any* stackexchange site? I know of `user:me`, but that seems to list only the questions on the current site.  And I had been searching the FAQ here, too.

[How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/how-can-i-view-all-my-unaccepted-questions-across-se) deals with it, but it's too complicated for a typical user. Isn't there a direct way to get the result?

Comment: No, there's no way beyond using a SEDE query.

Comment: Is part of the problem that `user:me` expands to a different user ID on each site? Could I use Google to query? Many companies fail to provide a good search service for their own sites, so Google is much better in such cases...

Comment: If you have a unique display name and the same name across all sites then yes, Google can help: https://www.google.co.uk/?q=site:stackexchange.com%20%22U.%20Windl%22%20-%22user%22 (for Stack Overflow you'll need another search as it's different domain)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/8847049/u-windl?tab=activity) has a list of your most recent 100 posts on all sites (questions and answers), sorted by date of creation. This includes answers and nothing that is deleted, but it’s probably your best bet.

(There is a link to your network profile in the upper right of any of your regular profile pages.)

Here is how to get there (partial screenshots only):

First locate the **Network profile** link.

[image: Locate **Network profile** link]

Then locate the **activity** tab.

[image: Locate **activity** tab]