# See questions I have not accepted answers on yet?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search for questions that I have asked and not accepted any answers to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16581/search-for-questions-that-i-have-asked-and-not-accepted-any-answers-to)

How can I view the questions on Stack Overflow that I haven't yet accepted answers on yet? I can't seem to raise my accept rate, even though I think I've just about accepted answers on all my questions...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A412082+hasaccepted%3A0

Answer (score 8):

Look at your profile, and click "Questions" to see all your questions. They are color-coded based on whether or not there is an accepted answer.

Additionally you could search for `user:me hasaccepted:0`, which will show you a list of all your questions with no accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

CHeck this tab:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/412082/codeguy?tab=questions

In the green "answers" box, the yellow/gold numbers have an accepted answer, the white ones don't

Comment: Unfortunately you have to visually filter out those questions.  The search would be the best option.