# Find all of my unaccepted questions across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, search, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I view all my unaccepted questions across SE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/how-can-i-view-all-my-unaccepted-questions-across-se)

I would like to find all of the questions I have posted on the Stack Exchange network that do not yet have an accepted answer. Is it possible to do this with the website's current features?

I know that it is possible to do this for individual sites using a search query with a "hasaccepted" parameter, but I don't know how to search for these questions across all sites.

Comment: My first guess would be run the "hasaccepted:0 user:me" search on stackexchange.com rather than an individual site, but I just tried it and it gave me garbage (such search features don't seem to apply to that particular site).

Comment: @Jim those features are built into SE's custom search, which the on-site search uses, but the all-site search uses standard Google which lacks those features

Comment: I figured as much. Worth a shot though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this would be a helpful feature with a real purpose.

The SE sites I ask questions on will usually be those whose domain I'm *not* an expert in. Hence, I will not be a regular to those sites, and it's shamefully often that I forget to accept an answer that helped me, only to come back to it months later.

A feature like this would help keep track of those questions.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: The answer to the question is to implement the needed feature.

Comment: @TravisBemrose I've added an answer on the duplicate that implements this feature by using SEDE. You can find my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259795/158100).