# Getting a list of questions I've asked for which I should accept an answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Is there a way I can get a list of questions I've asked for which I have yet to accept an answer? Better yet, can I filter that list to only questions which activity in, say, the last month?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching All sort of fancy stuffs are explained here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large number of questions without any answers and you are looking for your questions **with answers** in order to decide if you want to accept one, then you can add the `answers` search modifier as well:

```
user:2829764 hasaccepted:no answers:1
```

The components of this search are:

- **user:2829764**  -> Will search for all posts by you
- **hasaccepted:no** -> Will filter out any question with an accepted answer.  The `hasaccepted` modifier also implicitly filters out any answers so the `is:question` modifier is not needed
- **answers:1** -> Will filter out any question with 0 answers (only returns posts with 1 or more answers).

And it will return all questions asked by you without an accepted answer that have at least 1 answer

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2829764+hasaccepted%3Ano+answers%3A1

And you can combine this with the `lastactive` modifier to restrict this further based on the last activity date.  For example:

```
user:2829764 hasaccepted:no answers:1 lastactive:2014-01..2014-02
```

will return the results based on the previously mentioned criteria, but only for posts that were active since the beginning of January.

Comment: For others who are interested in the same thing--I learned from [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139429/find-all-of-my-unaccepted-questions-across-all-stack-exchange-sites#comment393067_139429) that such queries can only be run on one site at a time: "@Jim those features are built into SE's custom search, which the on-site search uses, but the all-site search uses standard Google which lacks those features."

Answer (score 5):

Using [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2829764+hasaccepted%3Ano+lastactive%3A2014-01..2014-03)

> user:2829764 hasaccepted:no lastactive:2014-01..2014-03

You can find your own posts that you haven't accepted an answer on in the specified time frame.

More information on creating your own query can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

Answer (score 3):

You have just asked 16 questions, you can go to your profile, click on [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2829764/kuzzooroo?tab=questions) and get a list of questions you have asked, the color difference would let your know whether you have accepted the answer for the question or not.

[image]

You can also enter a search query  like:

```
user:[yourID] is:question  hasaccepted:no
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can get a list of questions I've asked for which I have yet to accept an answer?

Sure:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2829764+is%3Aquestion++hasaccepted%3Ano

> Better yet, can I filter that list to only questions which activity in, say, the last month?

You can sort by date, to get the most recent to show up first; that should be sufficient:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2829764%20is%3aquestion%20%20hasaccepted%3ano