# Is there a way to view all questions you haven't accepted answers for?

Tags: support, questions, search, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search for questions that I have asked and not accepted any answers to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16581/search-for-questions-that-i-have-asked-and-not-accepted-any-answers-to)

Is there a way to view all questions you haven't accepted answers for? Or do you have to look through the whole list and see "have you considered accepting an answer?"